# Play Framework: PDF 0.9 module not playing nicely with JavaAPIforKml

Tags: java, playframework, pdf-generation, kml

My Play project currently depends on Play's `pdf module version 0.9` and `JavaAPIforKml 2.2.0` (used to create objects representing kml files).

Previously I was using `pdf module version 0.7` and everything was working fine.

Now that I have upgraded to version 0.9, all my tests for kml based classes now fail.  The exception I get is this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at     
play.classloading.ApplicationClassloader.loadClass(ApplicationClassloader.java:93)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:115)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:146)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:298)
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:223)
at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:131)
at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:833)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:287)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:286)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:285)
at 
com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:202)
at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:363)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:574)
at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:522)
at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.getJaxbContext(Kml.java:631)
at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.createMarshaller(Kml.java:640)
at de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml.marshal(Kml.java:682)
```

The part of the code that causes the exception is this:

```
de.micromata.opengis.kml.v_2_2_0.Kml kml = ...
kml.marshal(someByteArrayOutputStream); // This is the line that causes the exception
```

If I switch back to pdf module version 0.7, everything works again.  Does anyone know what I could do to keep using pdf module version 0.9 and have the kml tests to continue to work?

In case it helps, the pdf module version 0.9 has these dependencies:

```
core-renderer.jar
itest-2.1.7.jar
jaxen-1.1.jar
jtidy-r938.jar
shani-parser-v1.4.17.jar
xml-apis.jar
yahp-internal.jar
yahp.jar
```

While the JavaApiForKml version 2.2.0 has these dependencies:

```
jaxb-impl 2.2
jaxb-xjc 2.2
xmlunit 1.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get my build to work again however I don't particularly like the solution.  Firstly, I download the xerces2 library from apache.

I put the jar into the lib directory and the build worked.  This library never existed previously so I'm not sure how it worked before.

I then put the xerces jar in its own play "module" called xerces so that when running `play deps --sync` the xerces jar would not get wiped from the lib directory.  After running the build using this technique the build failed again!

So after more playing around, I thought it may have something to do with the ordering of the jars.  I renamed the xerces module I created to be called apache-xerces and re-ran the build and the build started working again!

Answer (score 1):

I also struggled with the Play! PDF module breaking my (previously working) XML parsing.

Thanks for sharing your solution, it helped a lot! Though there is a more elegant way to achieve it.

As xerces lives on maven central, you should be able to add this to your dependencies.yml:

```
- xerces -> xercesImpl 2.10.0
```

That way you don't need to create a module for it, or worry about it being overwritten when you sync.

(I'm using 2.10.0, but you can swap that out for whichever version is most appropriate)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because PDF module uses the jar file `xml-apis.jar` which adds `org.allcolor.xml.parser.CDocumentBuilderFactory` to the available DocumentBuilderFactory. Unfortunately, this document builder seems not handling very well some features, as the XPath evaluation.

When we add the Xerces library to the project, its DocumentBuilder supersedes the previous one and everything works fine. But this works by chance: it just happens that the Xerces DocumentBuilderFactory is the first one to be found.

In order to force the application to use the default DocumentBuilderFactory implementation I think that is preferable to define the corresponding system property, as defined in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newInstance()).

```
-Djavax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
```

Alternatively, we can create a new DocumentBuilderFactory instance explicitly indicating which implementation should be used:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance("com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl", null);
```